# How to calc percentage of coverage in an array of 1-100 using C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm

This is for an assignment so I would appreciate no direct answers; rather, any logic help with my algorithms (or pointing out any logic flaws) would be incredibly helpful and appreciated!

I have a program that receives "n" number of elements from the user to put into a single-dimensional array.
The array uses random generated numbers.
IE: If the user inputs 88, a list of 88 random numbers (each between 1 to 100) is generated).
"n" has a max of 100.

I must write 2 functions.

Function #1:

```
Determine the percentage of numbers that appear in the array of "n" elements.
So any duplicates would decrease the percentage.
And any missing numbers would decrease the percentage.
Thus if n = 75, then you have a maximum possible %age of 0.75 
(this max %age decreases if there are duplicates)
    
This function basically calls upon function #2. 

FUNCTION HEADER(GIVEN) = "double coverage (int array[], int n)"
```

Function #2:

```
Using a linear search, search for the key (key being the current # in the list of 1 to 100, which should be from the loop in function #1), in the array.
    
Return the position if that key is found in the array 
(IE: if this is the loops 40th run, it will be at the variable "39", 
and will go through every instance of an element in the array 
and if any element is equal to 39, all of those positions will be returned? 
I believe that is what our prof is asking)

Return -1 if the key is not found. 

Given notes = "Only function #1 calls function #2, 
and does so to find out if a certain value (key) is found among the first n elements of the array."

FUNCTION HEADER(GIVEN) = "int search (int array[], int n, int key)"
```

**What I really need help with is the logic for the algorithm.**

I would appreciate any help with this as I would approach this problem completely differently than our professor wants us.

My first thoughts would be to loop through function #1 for all variable keys of 1 through 100.
And in that loop, go to the search function (function #2), in which a loop would go through every number in the array and add to a counter if a number was (1)a duplicate or (2) non-existent in the array. Then I would subtract that counter from 100. Thus if all numbers were included in the array except for the #40 and #41, and then #77 was a duplicate , the total percentage of coverage would be 100 - 3 = 97%.

Although as I type this I think that may in of itself be flawed? ^ Because with a max of 100 elements in the array, if the only number missing was 99, then you would subtract 1 for having that number missing, and then if there was a duplicate you would subtract another 1, and thus your percentage of coverage would be (100-2) = 98, when clearly it ought to be 99.

And this ^ is exactly why I would REALLY appreciate any logic help. :)

I know I am having some problems approaching this logically.

I think I can figure out the coding with a relative amount of ease; what I am struggling witht he most is the steps to take. So any pseudocode ideas would be amazing!

*(I can post my entire program code so far if necessary for anyone, just ask, but it is rather long as of now as I have many other functions performing other tasks in the program)*

Comment: Thanks Theolodis for fixing my blockquotes.:) Not sure how I switched from being able to just type ">" to having to hit CMD+K. Haha.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to "loop through function #1". Function #1 computes the final answer, so you only want to call that once. However, the description of function #1 suggests that you should call function #2 from within the implementation of function #1 to compute the result.

Comment: My understanding based upon my professors notes (he gave us the function headers) is that we must use function #1 to loop through the numbers of 1 through 100. And use the search function #2 to compare the current number between 1 - 100 to all of the numbers in the array. 
 // The function header given for the function #2 is "int search (int array[], int n, int key)". The header for function #1 is "double coverage (int array[], int n)"

Comment: Yes, I understand all that ... maybe you're overthinking this. The question is simply to count the number of unique integers in a given collection. It shouldn't be more than a few lines.

Comment: Well I need logic help because I've had such little experience with C++, and unfortunately I am struggling as there is not much guidance with the textbook. And since the class is online there are no office hours and no interaction with the prof. I can think of simpler ways to do the assignment, but not with the given guidelines from our prof. The thing that throws me the most is having to return the position of the element in function#2? D:

Comment: The position is just a red herring. All you care about is whether a number is in your collection, i.e. whether the result of function #2 is not `-1`. The *actual* position doesn't matter.

Comment: Ah, makes sense! I was concerned about what we were supposed to do with the position. 
If the second function returns a -1, should I use a loop with a count set to 100% and then subtract 1 for all the positions that aren't in the array (Ie: they return -1, so looping through they just add -1 to a count of numbers to subtract)?

Comment: I'm not sure what to say without giving the whole thing away. For each of the numbers from 1 to 100 you want to know if the number is in your array...

Comment: I don't really see the problem with "giving the whole thing away"? I'm not asking for the answer, just logic help. If my logic is wrong, please tell me exactly where it is wrong. And how to fix it if possible. I understand the idea of for numbers 1-100 to know if the numbers are in the array. That was understood prior to my posting this question. Where I am struggling is what to do with the returned -1's now? How to actually calculate the percentage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be mistaken, but as I read it all you need to do is:

- write a function that loops through the array of n elements to find a given number in it. It would return the index of first occurence, or a negative value in case the number cannot be found in the array.
- write a loop to call the function for all numbers 1 to 100 and count the finds. Then divide the result by 100.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand this whole thing right, but 1 function you can do it, if you don't care about speed, it's better to put array into a `vector`, loop through 1..100 and use boost find function http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/find_nth.html. There you can compare current value with the second entry value in the vector, if it contains you decrease, not not decrease, if you want to find if the unique number is in array, use http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/. I don't understand, how the percentage decreases, so it's on your own and I don't rly understand second function, but if its linear search use again find.
P.S. Vector description http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/begin/.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately I must abide by the guidelines 100%. Haha. I know it's frustrating to have to stick to something so strictly when perhaps there is an easier way to do something. :(
We have not touched upon vectors yet in the class and thus are unable to use them. I will lose points if I do. Yikes!

Answer (score 0):

You want to know how many numbers in the range [1, 100] appear in your given array. You can search for each number in turn:

```
size_t count_unique(int array[], size_t n)
{
    size_t result = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i)
    {
        if (contains(array, n, i))
        {
            ++result;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

All you still need is an implementation of the containment check `contains(array, n, i)`, and to transform the unique count into a percentage (by using division).